# Initialization of static array of class objects inside class inside constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, arrays, list, static, initialization

I have a static array `PV` of class objects with fixed size 8. I want to initialize this array inside construtor initialization list. But i get errors:

> /base/Port.hpp:35: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
>
> /base/Port.hpp: In constructor 'io_port_t::io_port_t(uint16_t, uint16_t, uint16_t)':
>
> /base/Port.hpp:25: error: expected `(' before
>    '{' token
>
> /base/Port.hpp:25: error: no matching function for call to
>   'Pin::Pin()'

My code:

```
struct io_port_t
{
public:

    io_port_t(uint16_t pin, uint16_t ddr, uint16_t port) :
        PIN ((CReg)pin  ),
        DDR ((CReg)ddr  ),
        PORT((CReg)port ),
        P0(0, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
        P1(1, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
        P2(2, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
        P3(3, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
        P4(4, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
        P5(5, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
        P6(6, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
        P7(7, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
        PV{
            Pin(0, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
            Pin(1, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
            Pin(2, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
            Pin(3, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
            Pin(4, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
            Pin(5, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
            Pin(6, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT),
            Pin(7, &PIN, &DDR, &PORT)
        }
    { }

    CReg PIN;
    CReg DDR;
    CReg PORT;

    Pin P0;
    Pin P1;
    Pin P2;
    Pin P3;
    Pin P4;
    Pin P5;
    Pin P6;
    Pin P7;

    Pin PV[8];
};
```

When i remove initialization of `PV` from constructor initializer list it compiles fine. I was trying to change bracket `{` to `(` like `PV(` or `PV({` but I was still getting errors. How can I initialize `PV` array?

Comment: I think that the extended initialization list is only available since c++11.
Perhaps you should try to initialize in the constructor itself

Comment: Do you have C++11 or higher enabled?  A minimal example compiles here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/551c07ec0abec95a

Comment: You seem to know about arrays, why do you have variables like `P0` `P1` `P2`...?

Comment: Ok, I see this is related to compiler. I use "light" c++ compiler, so I think this is the reason. I tried my code at coliru.stacked-crooked.com and it worked. I am programming AVR microcontrolers using C++. So, I will put array initialization into constructor.

Comment: @VTT, sometimes when you use LCD (ex. hd44780) connected to microcontroller, you assign pins which has different port. Example: RS=PB5, E=PD0, DB4=PC1, ... and this is why I put P0, P1 members. But when you use common port (all pins are connected to PD), it is better to use Pin array like PV with an offset.